# Float list items around larger middle item

Tags: html, css, css-float, html-lists

This is a tough question to explain, so I've provided an example (not enough reputation to post an image). I would like to have list items wrap around (both to the left and right) of a taller list item in the middle of a wrapping category-type list.

```
1  2  3
4  2  5
6  7  8
```

As you can see, item 2 is twice as tall as the other list items (equivalent of rowspan 2 as a table cell). With just a float: left attribute, item 4 would appear to the right bottom of item 2, and 5,6,7 would be in row 3, and 8 on a new row 4. The space to the bottom left of 2 would be empty. Like this:

```
1  2  3
   2  4
5  6  7
8
```

I want the floated elements to fill this available space to the bottom left of 2 before being floated to the right of the element. Is this possible? Thanks!

EDIT: I forgot to mention that this should be a fluid layout, so if I drag my window smaller it will reduce to two columns and look something like this:

```
1  2
3  2
4  5
6  7
8
```

Comment: try `position:relative;margin-left:-100%` on the item that is next to free space.

Comment: Not doable if you want it to be dynamic (variable size of the elements).

Comment: http://masonry.desandro.com/ might do what you want.

Comment: @j08691 - he has got absolutely positioned elements... probably some js magic tricks...

Comment: Some fun with the blocks :)
http://jsfiddle.net/G48bZ/

Comment: Sorry guys, forgot to mention it should be a fluid layout. Edited above for more clarity. I won't be able to define a "column" or a "row" because column amount may change, and if I defined rows, with a resize elements would have to remove and change which row element they were a child of :/